# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Libraries.Classes.ScannerDeviceStore' to 'Libraries.Interfaces.IDeviceStore<Libraries.Models.ScaleDevice>'

Tags: c#

I have following interface:

```
  public interface IDeviceStore<T> where T : Device 
  {
    void Save(T device);
    T Get();
  }
```

And the implementation:

```
public class ScaleDeviceStore : IDeviceStore<ScaleDevice>
  {
    private ScaleDevice _device;

    public void Save(ScaleDevice device)
    {
      if (device != null)
      {
        return;
      }

      _device = device;
    }

    public ScaleDevice Get()
    {
      return _device;
    }
  }
```

So when I want to create an instance:

```
private IDeviceStore<Device> _createScannerStore()
    {
      return new ScannerDeviceStore();
    }
```

The compiler complain:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Libraries.Classes.ScannerDeviceStore' to 'Libraries.Interfaces.IDeviceStore<Libraries.Models.ScaleDevice>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have both `ScaleDeviceStore` and `ScannerDeviceStore`. Your second piece of code shows the former, and your third piece of code tries to use the latter.

Comment: That is, a `return (Libraries.Interfaces.IDeviceStore<Libraries.Models.ScaleDevice>)(new ScannerDeviceStore());` would work?